# How to implement MVC with QGraphicsScene as model?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qgraphicsscene

I am struggling with the MVC concept.

My current design:

- a subclass of `QGraphicsScene`, that implements a large number of properties:

  - `setPropertyAOnSelectedItems` / `getPropertyAOfSelectedItems`
  - `setPropertyBOnScene` / `getPropertyBOfScene`
- a subclass of `QGraphicsView` that implements a few properties (like zoom, centering, certain mouse or gesture actions)
- a UI containing the view and user tools to edit - set/read properties from scene
- other similar UI's with different design and editing a subset of the scene properties

Reading about how to implement MVC in Qt, at the moment I have the scene subclass pretending to be one giant "model" - except it doesn't expose the kind of functions from Qt's examples... index, row and column info seems useless, and to use a `data()` for the large number of complex properties seems ... not applicable (even if assigning a very large number of "roles").

The UI would be the View... That would allow multiple UIs to use the same model...

**But what would be the Controller ?**

Reading about "skinny" Controllers - it seems that in this situation I could have a Controller that does nothing but echoes the info from UI, to the scene, and back... And that seems useless !

Where would I put range checks/valid checks/unit conversions ? Is that the role of the controller ?
I would like to have a Validation class separate - where would that be in the MVC hierarchy ?

I have tried to read and adapt the MVC concept to my problem but I just can't see how to break it down...